# How to run TeX Live 2014 in Windows 8 64bit?

Tags: texlive, installing

I would like to run TeX Live 2014 in Windows 8 64bit. Installed TeX Live 2014 32bit.

When I try to run my first TeX program `first.tex` I get the following error message in command line:

```
warning: kpathsea: variable `TEXINPUTS' references itself (eventually).
warning: kpathsea: variable `TEXINPUTS' references itself (eventually).
warning: kpathsea: variable `TEXINPUTS' references itself (eventually).
```

What configuration is to be done in Windows8?

Comment: How did you installed TeXLive on windows? Why not better MikTeX?

Comment: MikTex is existing my system. I wanted to run both in parallel in the same system. MikTex is working very well. I do not find any problem with that

Comment: Well, that seems quite redundant, (in addition to being a waste of hard disk). I don't know if it's feasible to have 2 `TeX` distributions installed on the same system. It might be interference between the two and that your mistakes are due.

Comment: @Aradnix It's quite possible to run TeX Live and MiKTeX in parallel, and TeX Live is perfectly usable on Windows. I think as you suggest we need more detail on how the installation was done: using the standard setting a TL and MiKTeX set up are independent and `TEXINPUTS` is not even set by the installers!

Comment: @JosephWright is good to know it. I feared there might be a conflict when compiling to use the same paths or something. In any case, I don't know if it's possible, but it would be good to do a single installation of the packages and general `texaware`, and that administration of all that could be done in one either other without installing twice the same thing, or am I wrong?

Comment: Base on my experienced a few days ago, I had installed both miktex and texlive in my windows 7 and I bump in to some problems. As it turns out something goes wrong when you install two of them on your system.